# How can a control be notified when its parent receives and loses focus in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

As the title says, I'd like a component (say, a `label`) to be notified when it's *parent* (say, a `panel`) receives and loses focus. I wandered a bit in Delphi source, in hope of using `TControl.Notify`, but it's only used to notify child controls of some property changes like font and color. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for your own control (label)? On a form you can simply write OnEnter, OnExit event handlers for the parent (panel).

Comment: What are you trying to actually DO?  It sounds like you want to hack a kludge around a bug. But if you elucidate someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @WarrenP I'm using `JvGradientHeader` on a lot of my panels as captions, and I'd like to highlight the focused panel's title.

Comment: Do panels actually receive focus?

Comment: Assign a single set of OnEnter and OnExit event handlers to all of the panels. Inside of the handlers, you can loop through the Sender's children controls looking for a JvGradientHeader object and then update it as needed.

Comment: Another option would be to subclass each panel to catch the CM_FOCUSCHANGED message and then broadcast a custom-defined CM_PARENTFOCUSCHANGED message to the sender's children controls. You can then subclass the JvGradientHeader controls to catch that message.

Comment: This sounds like a good time to create a composite control that inherits from TPanel, and owns a JvGradientHeader. Then the Tpanel control exit and enter virtual methods can be overriden.  Object oriented programming is your friend.

Comment: @WarrenP Unfortunately not all my _containers_ are the same component. I found a component in the *TMS* component pack which highlights currently selected control. I'm gonna take a look at its source

Comment: @iManBiglari: Why not write a function that works the opposite of `TObject.Dispatch`? i.e.: send to child controls only.

Comment: @Jay because I don't want to modify the _container_ classes. As Remy and Warren mentioned above, I could easily create a descendant of `TPanel` and get the job done. But I'd rather have a _smart_ `JvGradientHeader` which can respond automatically.

Comment: @David Panels receive focus if `TabStop` is true or when manually set, but that's not a requisite here. I think OP means that whenever a (nested) child control on the panel receives focus, his control should be signalled. (Note that `Panel.OnEnter` ís fired in that case, but `Panel.Focussed` remains false.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever the active control in an application changes, a `CM_FOCUSCHANGED` message is broadcast to all controls. Simply intercept it, and act accordingly.

Also, I assumed that by *when it's parent (say, a panel) receives and loses focus* you mean whenever a (nested) child control on that parent/panel receives or loses focus.

```
type
  TLabel = class(StdCtrls.TLabel)
  private
    function HasCommonParent(AControl: TWinControl): Boolean;
    procedure CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged);
      message CM_FOCUSCHANGED;
  end;

procedure TLabel.CMFocusChanged(var Message: TCMFocusChanged);
const
  FontStyles: array[Boolean] of TFontStyles = ([], [fsBold]);
begin
  inherited;
  Font.Style := FontStyles[HasCommonParent(Message.Sender)];
end;

function TLabel.HasCommonParent(AControl: TWinControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  while AControl <> nil do
  begin
    if AControl = Parent then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
    AControl := AControl.Parent;
  end;
end;
```

If you don't like to subclass `TJvGradientHeader`, then it is possible to design this generically by the use of `Screen.OnActiveControlChange`:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHeaders: TList;
    procedure ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHeaders := TList.Create;
  FHeaders.Add(Label1);
  FHeaders.Add(Label2);
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := ActiveControlChanged;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHeaders.Free;
end;

function HasCommonParent(AControl: TWinControl; AMatch: TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  while AControl <> nil do
  begin
    if AControl = AMatch.Parent then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
    AControl := AControl.Parent;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject);
const
  FontStyles: array[Boolean] of TFontStyles = ([], [fsBold]);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to FHeaders.Count - 1 do
    TLabel(FHeaders[I]).Font.Style :=
      FontStyles[HasCommonParent(Screen.ActiveControl, TLabel(FHeaders[I]))];
end;
```

Note that I chose `TLabel` to demonstrate this works also for `TControl` derivatives.

Comment: I learned something nice. I always thought that only forms can have _message handlers_. Thanks a lot :-)